# Which branch is deployed on Elasticbeanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is there a command in AWS EB CLI tool that can tell me which git commit or branch is deployed on an environment?

Comment: I guess you're using aws eb cli v3.x ? in v2. its simple as `eb branch` - in v3.x not sure it can be done, if you saved your config `eb config save` the info might be present in `.elasticbeanstalk/saved_configs/<env-name>.cfg.yml` , you can also check `eb status --verbose` (sorry I dont have access to my account there so cannot check for sure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## You can only see the version label/number.

Versioning is independent of branches, and once you deploy a package, it looses any valuable relevance to the branch (which will quickly be changed and merged withother code/versions)

That is why the `eb deploy` command created a versioned package.

- Branch → Deployed Version
- NOT Branch ↔ Deployed Version

### Always deploy with a version label

`eb deploy --label 1.2.1`
Which will then be a human-readable entry in eb-status:

- **Deployed Version**

## eb status

```
Environment details for: ServerA
  Application name: YourApp
  Region: us-west-1
  Deployed Version: 1.2.1
  Environment ID: e-asdkfjhiwje
  Platform: Magic running Node
  Tier: WebServer-Standard
  CNAME: servera.elasticbeanstalk.com
  Updated: 2017-02-11 15:15:55.044400+00:00
  Status: Ready
  Health: Green
```

Comment: Very helpful, both an answer ("no, you can't") and a workaround ("but here's what")!